# htaccess method / parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm setting up some rewrite rules with htaccess in my apache server.

For example, all files that ends with .php are directed to the same files without the extention.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This way, i have the page http://server.com/page.php redirected to http://server.com/page

well, thats the tricky part, i have to write a special rule, that redirects http://server.com/page2.php?id=4 to http://server.com/page2/4

How can i do that?

I've already tried:

```
RewriteRule ^page2/(.*)$ page2.php?id=$1 [NC,L] //and [QA]
```

I had no luck putting this code in the end of the first code.

Comment: Try putting it first. Otherwise, since `page2.php.php` doesn't exist, first rule applies and `[L]` ends Rewrite. Also, it should be `[QSA]`.

Comment: @msg nope, that way the server returns 500 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(\d*)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2 [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: it worked partially. Now other errors are showed such as: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (slides.min.jquery.js, line 0)

Comment: You will have to check your http server's error log file as to what resource is actually targeted after the rewriting has been applied. Also rewrite logging is a good tool for that. A wild guess: could it be that you implemented those rules in a dynamic configuration file located no in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of your object hierarchy, but somewhere else? In that case change the target from an absolute to a relative path, so remove the leading slash.